# This code does not show any table view why?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have put a `UINavigationController` in main.storyboard and name it to as "TableViewController" and named the Prototype cell as "Cell". everything is clear and build is succeeded but there is nothing to show the table view instead a white blank table view. kindly suggest me a solution or your ideas. 
Here is the code in ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {


struct Objects {
    var sectionName : String!
    var sectionObjects : [String]!
}

var objectsArray = [Objects]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    objectsArray  = [Objects(sectionName: "General", sectionObjects: ["150/23","A: 98","W: 76","B: 89", "Quantity: 5kg"]),Objects(sectionName: "General", sectionObjects: ["150/23","A: 98","W: 76","B: 89", "Quantity: 5kg"]),Objects(sectionName: "General", sectionObjects: ["150/23","A: 98","W: 76","B: 89", "Quantity: 5kg"]),Objects(sectionName: "General", sectionObjects: ["150/23","A: 98","W: 76","B: 89", "Quantity: 5kg"])]

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView , cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"Cell") as UITableViewCell!

    cell?.textLabel?.text = objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]

    return cell!


}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objectsArray[section].sectionObjects.count
}

 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return objectsArray.count

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{
    return objectsArray[section].sectionName
}
}
```

Comment: swift 3.0 ya 2.0?

Comment: Are your cells being made? Check in the debug view heirarchy.

Comment: I assume you meant `UITableViewController`, not `UINavigationController`.

Comment: swift 3.0 @HimanshuMoradiya

Comment: @shallowThought what should I do? replace the UITableviewcontroller with UINavigationViewcontroller in Class line number 2?? i replaced it gives errors

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `numberOfSectionsInTableView` just to see if it is called. I suspect it is not and something is wrong in storyboard. In this case, show what you have done in Storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

It's because your implementation doesn't override proper method. After changing

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView , cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->UITableViewCell {
```

to

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

works for me.

Comment: thanx for you suggestion but it still not working just white blank table view is there i want my objects printed.

Comment: Another thing I can think of is that: "I have put a UINavigationController in main.storyboard and name it to as "TableViewController" and named the Prototype cell as "Cell"." You should change class of UITableViewController instead UINavigationController. If it isn't the case then I don't know, as I put down your code (with my small fix) and it works.

Comment: thanx for your efforts but it still same

Comment: @Xcodian Solangi for start chceck if methods are called. If not - check if table delegate and data source are set correctly (for example print table.delegate on viewDidAppear). I don't see in code above setting these properties but they could also be set from xib / storyboard or class extension.